# Can I replace an existing image in the same folder, in a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have developed a Metro app. I have a page that saves the user's selected image. When I choose the image in the pictures folder, an error will occur:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

But if I choose from another folder, everything will proceed smoothly and save the image name into the database.

Here is the snippet:

```
if (file != null)
{
    StorageFolder documentsFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
    output = await file.CopyAsync(documentsFolder, 
                                  file.Name.ToString(), 
                                  NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

Comment: I dont think your title reflects your actual question very well.  It seems like your title should be something like `Error occurs when opening image from pictures folder`

Comment: What do you mean by _another folder_? Have you added capability to access pictures library in manifest?

Comment: did you try to selecting 'No Authentication Required' from 'Network DTC Access'...??

Comment: @Xyroid I have added the capability. Another means example I picked a image and the path is "Libraries\Pictures\Examples\example.png" than if won't have any error. If I chose the image from "Libraries\Pictures\example.png" than it will have error. My purpose is to let user pick the image than it store the image name into the database than CopyAsync the image chosen to the Pictures Folder. Thanks.

Comment: @AurangzebHalepoto Sorry what you mean by that ? Thanks.

Comment: check out this link [filesavepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571152/how-to-save-existing-storagefile-using-filesavepicker)